# javascript calendar insert variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, events

I'm using a calendar script to show event dates. I have my events in a variable file called `eventdates`.

I want to include `eventdates` here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: [
             eventdates;
        ]
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })
});
```

But that's not working. I don't know how to fix that because I grab the events from an array.

Comment: `events: eventdates`?

Comment: Maybe it should be `events: eventdates`. There is not much you tell us about the problem/context, so all we can do is **guess**.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: [
             eventdates
        ]
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })
});
```

or use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: eventdates
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })
});
```

if `eventdates` is already an array.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make sure that your `events` are stored as an array and then you can use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: eventdates
    })
});
```

take a look at this [link](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/) for proper usage